# For what values is $x + y = z$ and $a^x + a^y = a^z$?

Tags: number-theory

I came across this question while trying to solve an equation with a friend. Obviously the statement
$$x + y = z \implies a^x + a^y = a^z$$
Is false. However, I'm a bit curious if there are any other solutions for $x, y, z, a$ such that this statement is true other then $x = y = z = 0$ and how they may/may not be generalized? I only managed to find $x = y = z = 0$ and I feel like there are no others but I was unable to prove this.

Comment: $x=y=1,z=a=2{}$

Comment: Actually it is false for $x=y=z=0$. $a^0+a^0=a^0\iff1+1=1$.

Comment: Since $x + y = z$, for any base $b$, $b^{x+y} = b^z$. In particular, $a^{x+y} = a^z$, so you're left to find the cases where $a^{x+y} = a^x + a^y$, i.e., those where $a^x a^y = a^x + a^y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $x \le y $. Dividing throughout by $a^x $ :

$1+a^{y-x}=a^{z-x} $

This is, there are consecutive powers of $a $ (which differ by 1).

Obviously this only happens when

$a=2$ , $ x=y=1$ , $z=2$

Answer (score 1):

This is true for $a=z=2$ and $x=y=1$. 
$2^1+2^1=2^2 ⟹2+2=4$

But I think because of the addition on the LHS, there will not be any other examples with integers-- at least none that are interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for positive integers, note that $a^x | a^z-a^x =a^y$ and similarly $a^y|a^z-a^y=a^x$. Hence, $x=y$.

The equation then boils down to

$$2a^x=a^z$$ which is trivial to solve.